# Are there any good music mixers available, equivalent to Windows "MP3 Tunes"?

Tags: software-recommendation, music, music-player

In Windows my dad used to have a program called **MP3 Tunes**. I have tried running it with **Wine**, and it worked. But strange things kept happening to the program, so it's not a reliable way to play music.

Basically I just want to have 2 players (in a single window) with these features:

- Preloading tracks in a player without immediately starting them.
- Fading from one track to the other.
- A timer on each player.

These features are also desired, but not required:

- Microphone input.
- Prelistening before loading a song in a player (through a seperate sound card).
- Pitch/Tempo control.
- Just being able to browse folders in the filesystem (without things like a *music library*).

Here are some screenshots of the program to clarify what I'm looking for:
[image: MP3 Tunes v2 (v1 was much better)]
[image: The largest accurate screenshot I found of v1]

Comment: There is Mixxx in the repositories that does some of what you want, sadly it does not work with pulseaudio.

Comment: @Sabacon Are you sure? Did some research and found this, it may be of help with getting Mixxx to work in PulseAudio: http://www.mixxx.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=132

Comment: It kinda works with Pulseaudio, but I've tried Mixxx a long time ago and it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: ... Maybe if it was easy to create a custom skin for it I'd manage to cook something up, but then there's still this issue: http://minus.com/mspJcANFp#1 Mixxx and Compiz don't seem to be very good friends. Oh fiddlesticks, I didn't record the sound in that screen recording >.< Anyway, from the moment Compiz has to do something, Mixxx starts lagging. A few seconds after the effects finishes the lagging stops.

Comment: @Icedrake I came across that forum you pointed to and tried what is suggested there without any luck, I am on Ubuntu 10.1 maybe that is the problem.

Comment: I'm on 10.10 and Mixxx works :p Just not what I'm looking for I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the java based [Ultramixer](http://www.ultramixer.com/download.html#tab_linux).

[image: Ultramixer]

*[Features](http://www.ultramixer.com/index.php?cn=products&c2=ultramixer&c3=features) of the free version:*

- AAC/M4A file support
- Fullscreen and tray mode
- MiniMode Player
- Variable pitch range (up to -/+ 50%)
- Database-driven file archive
- Realtime-BPM Counter
- Support of skinning for the user interface
- Cue points
- 3-Band-Equalizer / EQ-Kill-Buttons
- Import / Export of M3U lists
- FileArchive detail search
- Manual Talkover
- Monitoring over headhones
- Multi-soundcard support
- Automix function
- Switchable fading modes

[Installation instructions](http://www.ultramixer.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=42&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) *from Ultramixer community forum.*

Comment: I've tried that one in the past, several times. It has, so far, always failed me. UI elements missing, elements not reacting when you click on them, frquent crashing, ... So this is not really what I'm looking for. Maybe I'll give it another try to see if anything has changed between the last time I tried it and now, though. It also seems like the Linux version isn't being maintained anymore...

Comment: @RobinJ I haven't used it but it seems quite suitable to your requirements, if it's running :)

Comment: @RobinJ Have you tried if it's working for you?

Comment: The interface doesn't respond when I try to click on... basically anything :/

Comment: @RobinJ Try to run it from the terminal so that you can check for error and weird messages that may appear while using the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to look if you want an application that has **only** those features, but there are a couple of very robust audio mixing solutions for Linux, closer in functionality to Garageband for OSX.

Try [Ardour](http://www.ardour.org), billed as "a complete digital audio workstation"

[image: Ardour 2.5 showing plugins, crossfade editing and both main windows, and on the far right, the QJackctl connection dialog for JACK.]

Or [LMMS - the Linux Multimedia Studio](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/).

[image: sample browser, Song-Editor, Beat+Bassline-Editor and some controllers]